# CSS Lists alignment and responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am trying to make the following small feature list work in a responsive web page and I get really stuck trying to keep these elements aligned when viewed on smaller screens. Is it even possible ?

https://jsfiddle.net/b8zvo918/

```
Payment terms :  CC
Price :          Average
Quality :        Mediocre
Colors :         white


<ul>
      <li><span class="left w25">Payment terms :</span>CC</li>
      <li><span class="left w25">Price :</span> Average</li>
      <li><span class="left w25">Quality :</span> Mediocre</li>
      <li><span class="left w25">Colors :</span>white</li>
```

```
.w25 {
    width: 25%;
}
.left {
    Float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make rows to prevent wrapping from going into the next line...something like this for your row class:

```
.row:before,
.row:after { display:table; content: " "; }
.row:after { clear:both; }
```

Then your HTML, something more like this:

```
<div class='row'>
   <span class="left w25">Payment terms :</span>
   <span class="left w75">CC</span>
</div>
<div class='row'>
   <span class="left w25">Price :</span>
   <span class="left w75">Average</span>
</div>
<div class='row'>
   <span class="left w25">Quality :</span>
   <span class="left w75">Mediocre</span>
</div>
</div class='row'>
   <span class="left w25">Colors :</span>
   <span class="left w75">white</span>
</div>
```

You may also need to implement different sizes for different resolutions using @media CSS so that you have w25 for large screens but w50 for small screens.  Bootstrap 3 does this by doing:

```
<span class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3'>Colors:</span>
```

In bootstrap, the above tag will take up 50% width at phone resolution, but only 25% at all other resolutions...and there are a million and one other ways to finagle it to what you need.